# Checking for collision for maze game in canvas

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to develop a maze game in canvas. I have drawn the maze manually such as

```
    context.moveTo(100,700);
    context.lineTo(100,600);
    context.lineTo(200,600);
    context.lineTo(200,500);
```

and there are many more. I want to move the object through these lines without moving beyond those border.

For this I have tried the following code :

```
function right() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    art();
    myImage11.src = "Point.png";
    x += 20;

    if ((x + 20 < 50)) {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        checkcollision();
        if (collision == 1) {
            x -= 20;
            collision = 0;
        }

        context.drawImage(myImage11, x, y, 50, 50);
    }
```

my checkcollision function does

```
function checkcollision() {
    var myImage11 = context.getImageData(x, y, 10, 10);
    var pix = myImage11.data;
    for (var i = 0; n = pix.length, i < n; i += 4) {
        if (pix[i] == 0) {
            collision = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Please help to solve this!!!
Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your `checkcollision` function do?

Comment: function checkcollision() {
   var myImage11 = context.getImageData(x, y, 50, 50);
   var pix = myImage11.data;
   for (var i = 0; n = pix.length, i < n; i += 19) {
   if (pix[i] == 0) {
   collision = 1;
  }
  }
  }

Comment: each pixel should be 4(RGBA) entries in the array (so a 10x10 =arraysize 400), http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_getimagedata2

Comment: I changed it to 4. But it doesn't work

Comment: You should check for a security issue with images (CORS), which leads to a blank imageData : remove any image draw to test this. Share a small version of the game on jsfiddle to help us help you.

Comment: Check the imageData values, it's possible that the pix[i] has a value but the Alpha value is set to 0 (pix[i+3] )

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to extrapolate the exact workings of the current scenario, like the collision only checked when `x + 20 < 50`, but the problem probably is in the area from which the getImageData is obtained: the x and y positions of the 'avatar' with a width of 10 (`context.getImageData(x, y, 10, 10);` ) This would check if the left side of the newavatar position has a collision, but not the right side in which direction the move was made. For that something like x + avatarWidth- XMovement and a width of XMovement should be checked.

Perhaps not entirely corresponding with your current setup, but made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zcr1qfta/) that emulates the movement. In it the entire avatar target position is checked for a quicker setup, but could be optimized to use the new overlaps if needed.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = 100, y = 200;
var imgWidth = 50, imgHeight = 50;

var checkcollision = function(){ //checks collision of the entire 'avatar' rectangle. This can be done more efficiently by only checking the moved to area, but that would require different parameters per direction.
    var data = context.getImageData(x , y, imgWidth, imgHeight).data;
    return data.some(function(p){ return  p != 0;});
} 

function right() {
    context.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    art(); //draw maze
    //myImage11.src = "Point.png";

    var curx= x;
    x+=20;   

    while(checkcollision() && x > curx){ //while collision decrease x (note, this could be more efficient by just checking the new position overlap)
        x--;
    } 

    drawAvatar();
}


function art(){
    context.moveTo(100,400); //decreased y a bit to keep it easier viewable while testing
    context.lineTo(100,300);
    context.lineTo(200,300);
    context.lineTo(200,200);
    context.stroke();
}

function drawAvatar(){
    //context.drawImage(myImage11, x, y, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    context.fillRect(x,y,imgWidth,imgHeight);  
}

art();drawAvatar();
```

Answer (score 0):

Image data does do some weird stuff
Sometimes the color you draw is off a little.
Check the diffrence between y=98,99,100
http://jsfiddle.net/15wsszw4/

the formula gets the RED value of a pixel at x,y

```
console.log('R:'+imgData.data[y*4*c.width+x*4])
```